# argument mismatch; invalid functional descriptor for lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, refactoring, jdbi

I am using the [jdbi](https://jdbi.org/) library like so:

```
try {
    return jdbi.withHandle(handle -> handle
        .createQuery("...")
        .mapTo(String.class)
        .one());
} catch (final JdbiException e) {
    if (DatabaseExceptionChecker.isTransientException(e)) {
        throw new MyCustomException("Transient database exception", e);
    } else {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

This try catch pattern is repeated a few times, with various different queries passed to the `jdbi.withHandle` method. Another example:

```
try {
    return jdbi.withHandle(handle -> handle
        .createUpdate("...")
        .execute());
} catch (final JdbiException e) {
    if (DatabaseExceptionChecker.isTransientException(e)) {
        throw new MyCustomException("Transient database exception", e);
    } else {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

The `jdbi.withHandle` method has this signature:

```
public <R, X extends Exception> R withHandle(HandleCallback<R, X> callback) throws X {
```

I am trying to find a way to reduce the duplication around the try-catch, so that I can use something like this instead:

```
handleTransientExceptions(() -> jdbi.withHandle(handle -> handle
        .createQuery("...")
        .mapTo(String.class)
        .one())
}
```

i.e. the `handleTransientExceptions` function would contain the try-catch boilderplate.

I've begun with the following:

```
@FunctionalInterface
private interface JdbiCall
{
    public <R, X extends Exception> R call() throws X;
}

public <R, X extends Exception> R handleTransientExceptions(final JdbiCall jdbiCall) throws MyCustomException
{
    try {
        return jdbiCall.call();
    } catch (final JdbiException e) {
        if (DatabaseExceptionChecker.isTransientException(e)) {
            throw new MyCustomException("Transient database exception", e);
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

however, when I try to call it like this:

```
return handleTransientExceptions(() -> jdbi.withHandle(handle -> handle
        .createQuery("...")
        .mapTo(String.class)
        .one())
}
```

I get the error:

```
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R,X
    (argument mismatch; invalid functional descriptor for lambda expression
      method <R,X>()R in interface com.acmecorp.MyService.JdbiCall is generic)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types cannot be inferred, because your functional interface `JdbiCall` doesn't have neither generics at the class declaration level nor parameters for `call` method by which these types can be inferred. So, your FI might look like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface JdbiCall<R, X extends Exception> {
    R call() throws X;
}
```

and `handleTransientExceptions` method:

```
public <R, X extends Exception> R handleTransientExceptions(final JdbiCall<R, X> jdbiCall) throws Exception {
    try {
        return jdbiCall.call();
    } catch (final JdbiException e) {
        if (DatabaseExceptionChecker.isTransientException(e)) {
            throw new MyCustomException("Transient database exception", e);
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Also it can be simplified to:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface JdbiCall<R> {
    R call() throws Exception;
}
```

`handleTransientExceptions` method:

```
public <R> R handleTransientExceptions(final JdbiCall<R> jdbiCall) throws Exception {
    try {
        return jdbiCall.call();
    } catch (final JdbiException e) {
        if (DatabaseExceptionChecker.isTransientException(e)) {
            throw new MyCustomException("Transient database exception", e);
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```